# How to test the mobile application for fresher?

Tags: manual-testing

I am a fresher right now and I want to test the mobile application (Android / iOS) so how to start for testing in the beginning.

Comment: You should understand and find out more about basic testing first such as test types/technique, test documentation, bug reporting, etc.

Then, you should learn about your mobile application. Pay attention to your software documentation (SRS) to learn about the functionalities, expected behavior, is it a native app or hybrid app? If it is a hybrid app learn about cross browser testing.

To put it simply, it's too broad and unclear what you are asking for. You should ask more specific question.

Comment: here, some list of links would be helpful to you

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-application-testing/
http://www.guru99.com/mobile-testing.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mobile_testing/index.htm

hope, you like it

Comment: Your answer is helpful for me (Kaushal Patel) Thank You